# How do I get 'puma' to start, automatically, when I run `rails server` (like Thin does)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

Normally, when you run `rails server` it starts Webrick.  If you install the 'thin' gem, then 'thin' starts instead.  I would like to do the same thing with the 'puma' server.

I see that the `start` command within railties (lib/rails/commands) calls super, but I can't find what the various options for 'super' are.  I have also reviewed many references to Rails within 'thin'.

I found a Changelog entry entitled "Added Thin support to script/server. #488 [Bob Klosinski]" from Oct. of 2008, but that code area has changed significantly since that commit (a93ea88c0623b4f65af98c0eb55924c335bb3ac1).

If someone could direct me to the right section of code, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

After some digging, I've found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14911994/604526

To make Puma the default, paste this code into script/rails above require 'rails/commands':

```
require 'rack/handler'
Rack::Handler::WEBrick = Rack::Handler.get(:puma)
```

Puma is the default server now if you use `rails s`

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Puma 1.6.3 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

### Rails 4

With Rails 4 you simply have to add the puma-gem to the Gemfile. (Tested with Rails 4.0.2 and Puma 2.6.0)

Comment: This didn't work to me. But I think that is because my app is using thin.

Comment: How do I do the reverse? I do not want puma to load by default in development.

Answer (score 19):

At least in Rails 4, you just need to add the following to your Gemfile

```
gem 'puma'
```

then run 'bundle', and then when you run 'rails server' and Puma will be used.

Comment: This works. Now if only I could figure out how to make it automatically load config/puma.rb when running `rails server`...

Comment: echo 'alias start_puma="bundle exec puma -p 3000 -S ~/puma -C config/puma.rb"' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
 THEN USE start_puma

Comment: Just tested on Rails 4.2 and running `bundle exec rails s` will launch puma and load the configuration settings from `config/puma.rb` all automatically.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me. Ruby 2.0.0 Rails 3.2.13  Puma 1.6.3

```
rails s puma
```

Comment: This bit me because ARGV[0] is not empty.  reload_libs loads lib/tasks/* and I had the assumption that if ARGV[0] was set, that I wanted to execute it as a command.

Answer (score 2):

[Puma documentation](https://github.com/puma/puma#rackup) suggests that you prepend `#\ -s puma` to your `config.ru`.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried it.  No luck.  Still get "Booting WEBrick" or "Booting Thin".  I wonder if this is a Rails bug?

Comment: @MattScilipoti It must be something with Rack. But I don't think it's a bug, rather you are just missing some settings.