# No logging/info with Rails and Heroku local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My Rails app is on Heroku and needs access to S3. As such, I have a `.env` file at the root of my directory with the AWS authentication bits. Simply running `rails s` will not use the env file, so I need to test my server with `heroku local`. However, this will not spit out any of the standard rails output. I did try `heroku logs` and `heroku logs -t`.

My procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

My env file:

```
RACK_ENV=development
PORT=3000
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=MYSECRETACCESSKEYID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=mySECRETaccessKEY
S3_BUCKET=my-bucket
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
```

After running `heroku local`:

```
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
1:33:45 PM web.1 |  Ignoring http_parser.rb-0.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine http_parser.rb --version 0.6.0
1:33:46 PM web.1 |  Puma starting in single mode...
1:33:46 PM web.1 |  * Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Code Name
1:33:46 PM web.1 |  * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
1:33:46 PM web.1 |  * Environment: development
1:33:48 PM web.1 |  * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
1:33:48 PM web.1 |  Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Expected results: whenever I make a request to the endpoint, I expect it to log the endpoint, the SQL commands, and the errors, like it usually does.

Comment: Sorry for such a dummy recommendation, but did you checked your log level inside config/environments/ENV_NAME?

Comment: No problem! They seem to be fine. `development.rb` doesn't have anything mentioning logs, so I set it to `config.log_level = :debug`, but still not output. `production.rb` was already set at debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Since we are not calling `rails s` directly, (my procfile is calling `bundle exec puma`), I looked on StackOverflow for similar questions involving puma and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862949/puma-show-full-logs-when-run-server-with-config-file).

I needed to open a second terminal and run `tail -f logs/development.log`.